# What portion of the electromagnetic spectrum do cats see?

Tags: eyes, vision, feline

I have seen numerous articles and various information about how cats and dogs see into the ultraviolet spectrum with interesting artistic renderings such as this:
[image: Cat UV Spectrum Example]
http://www.livescience.com/40459-what-do-cats-see.html

But I have been unable to find any specific parameters of what wavelength boundaries actually exist for cats.

We know that humans see from around [750 to 400 nm](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/ems3.html), but what would a cat's range be?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Short answer**
Spectral sensitivity of cats indeed ventures into the UV, but not beyond ~320 nm. Their maximum is likely similar to ours, i.e., ~750 nm.

**Background**
The spectral sensitivity of **blue cones** (photoreceptors detecting low wavelengths) of many species, including humans and cats, **extends into the UV** range (Fig. 1).

[image: cone spectra]
<sup>Fig. 1. Human cone absorption spectra. Source: [University of Kentucky](https://www.unm.edu/~toolson/human_cone_response.htm)</sup>

However, the various structures in the eye, most notably the **lens, filter out UV** in humans (Fig. 2). Indeed, **surgical removal of the lens** in humans results in **enhanced sensitivity to UV light** below 420 nm ([Griswold & Stark, 1992](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/1455745)).

[image: transmission spectra]
<sup>Fig. 2. Human transmission spectra. Source: [Columbia University](http://www.ciesin.org/docs/001-569/001-569.html)</sup>

In the **cat**, however, the **lens transmits a large portion of the UV light** in the range of **320 - 400 nm**, while primates transmit virtually no light of these wavelengths. Figure 3 shows the lens transmission spectra of various species. At 50% transmission the second (dotted) line from the left is the cat (50% transmission at ~340 nm), while a primate (squirrel monkey, species representative for humans and other primates) in this graph is line number 7 from the left with (50% transmission at ~410 nm). Hence, **cat lenses absorb less light in the UV region**, but transmission is virtually **nil at 320 nm** (Fig. 3). Given that their cones, just like humans, are sensitive to UV, we can reasonably expect that cats can see in the UV region including wavelengths of 320 nm and up. Cats also have the 560 nm (red) cones, like we do, so their maximum wavelength is expectedly similar to ours (~750 nm).

[image: Lens transmission]
<sup>Fig. 3. Lens transmission spectra of various species. Source: [Douglas & Jeffery, 2014](http://rspb.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/281/1780/20132995)</sup>

<sub>**References**

- [Douglas & Jeffery, *Proc R Soc B* (2014); **281**: 20132995](http://rspb.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/281/1780/20132995)

- [Griswold & Stark, *Vis Res* (1992); **32**(9): 1739-43](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/1455745)</sub>

Comment: So is it theoretically possible that I could surgically adjust my lens somehow to obtain some sort of extra vision?

Comment: @leekaiinthesky - Correct - I have added some text + a reference on aphakia (eyes without a lens) and increased UV sensitivity in humans

Comment: Here is a real life account of a very interesting fellow who had this experience after cataract surgery: http://www.komar.org/faq/colorado-cataract-surgery-crystalens/ultra-violet-color-glow/ @leekaiinthesky

Comment: Aren't cats missing red cones? That might make them less sensitive to long wavelengths than humans. Too bad there is no spectral plot for cats.

Comment: Cats also have the 560 nm (red) cones, like we do, so their maximum wavelength is expectedly similar to ours (~750 nm). Cats indeed cannot see red, i don't know what this conclusion is not corrected.